# insert confirmation behavior for an element while stopping the element's other event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Goal: I'd like to be able to decouple a given element's confirmation behavior from other event handlers it might have bound to it.  so given the following trivial example

```
var someApp = {
  "init": function(){
     $("a").click(someApp.doAnchorStuff); 
     $("button").click(someApp.doButtonStuff); 
     $("#submitButton").click(someApp.doSubmitStuff); 
     $("a, button, #submitButton").click(someApp.confirmAction); 
    }, 
  "doAnchorStuff": function(){//stuff},
  "doButtonStuff": function(){//stuff},
  "doSubmitStuff": function(){//stuff},
  "confirmAction" : function(){
        //intercept the flow of control and freeze everything, no other 
        //handlers on the elements this is being triggered on get called
        //display confirm dialog. 
        //IF user confirms, unfreeze, let the other handlers get triggered. 
        //If Not, do not let other event handlers get triggered
}
}

$(function(){
    someApp.init(); 
});
```

If this doesn't make sense, I'm happy to clarify.

a NON-working fiddle example :) http://jsfiddle.net/7jbt9/

Comment: You need to get the `confirmAction` occurring before other handlers, then `return false`, which should stop other default handlers happening.  To stop all handlers call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` on the event passed in then `return false`. The events are called in the order they are bound, so bind the `confirmAction` first.

Comment: how would you cause the confirmAction to happen first?  I added a fiddle putting that event handler first in the order of the code but it didn't work...not sure the right way to enforce an order...

Comment: It's the `$("a, button, #submitButton").click(someApp.confirmAction);` line that needs to happen before the other `.click()` event binding calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do to make this work:

1. **The confirmAction click handler needs to be attached first.** Doing this will make it so that it will be executed first in the chain.
2. **Call the stopImmediatePropagation() method on the event object passed to the callback function.** This will stop any other callbacks for that event from being executed.

> ```
> "confirmAction": function(e) {
>     if (!confirm("Continue?")) {
>         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
>     }
> }
> ```